# A little question about entropy (Basic Thermodynamics)

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, heat-engine

1. Suppose I have connected a source temperature $T_{so}$ and a sink temperature : $T_{si}$. So I get work $W = Q(1-T_{si}/T_{so})$, where $Q$ is the heat energy transferred due to temperature difference.
2. Divide the process in two parts. Suppose we have another sink temperature: $T_o$. Where $T_o$ is the least temperature achievable. When we at first connect the source and $T_o$, the system does work $W_1$. Then when I forcefully transfer $Q$ from $T_o$ to the sink, this second part of the process might be something like a refrigerator. We have to apply some work $W_2$. Assuming $W_1 > W_2$, where does the extra work go? Does the entropy  increase ? And what is the difference between the first process and the second process?

Summarizing, in the second process between $T_{so}$ and To we get a work, $W_1 = Q(1-T_o/T_{so})$ but some energy gets wasted. Then between $T_{si}$ and $T_o$ we have to do work, $W2=-Q(1-T_o/T_{si})$. It can be proven that this part actually decreases the entropy, if energy is not lost in any piece of the process. So the energy that is not converted to work increases entropy. Plus extra information : I extracted $Q-W_2$ from $T_o$ to keep the whole process similar to process 1.

Comment: Interesting question. I don’t quite follow what you are doing on step 2. Can you add a diagram?

Comment: Hello! I have edited your question using MathJax (LaTeX) math typesetting. For future questions, you can refer to [MathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020/). Thanks!

Comment: @boyfarrell I don't know how to add a diagram. sorry m8

Comment: @boyfarrell first I get work from 1st part then I use some part of it to transfer Q energy to sink . It kinda sounds like a relay race .

Comment: Is $T_{o}<T_{si}$?

Comment: @BobD yes or you can assume T0<<<<<Tsi but To is NOT 0 kelvin

Comment: Ok, then by “extra work” are you thinking more work is done in scenario 2 than 1?

Comment: Never ever use Bold face in such a way please, consider the format in other questions and try to improve readability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

**Case[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTxjR.png)** $T_o$ is not present
We can see that in that case, $\eta=\lvert\frac{W}{Q_{source}}\rvert=1-\frac{T_{si}}{T_{So}}$
So, $|W|=|Q_{source}|\Big(1-\frac{T_{si}}{T_{So}}\Big)$

**Case[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/25pTf.png)** $T_o$ is present between $T_{so}$ and $T_{si}$
In that case $T_{so}>T_o>T_{si}$
$|W_1|=|Q_{source}|\Big(1-\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}\Big)\tag{1}$
and $|W_2|=|Q_o|\Big(1-\frac{T_{si}}{T_{o}}\Big)\tag{2}$
As $\lvert\frac{Q_{source}}{Q_o}\rvert=\frac{T_{so}}{T_o}$
$\implies |Q_o|=|Q_{source}|\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}$

Put $Q_o$ in (2),
$|W_2|=|Q_{source}|\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}\Big(1-\frac{T_{si}}{T_{o}}\Big)=|Q_{source}|\Big(\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}-\frac{T_{si}}{T_{so}}\Big)$

So, net work done = $|W_1+W_2|=|Q_{source}|\Big(1-\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}\Big)+|Q_{source}|\Big(\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}-\frac{T_{si}}{T_{so}}\Big)$
$\implies |W_1+W_2|=|Q_{source}|\Big[\Big(1-\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}\Big)+\Big(\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}-\frac{T_{si}}{T_{so}}\Big)\Big]$
So, $|W_1+W_2|=|Q_{source}|\Big(1-\frac{T_{si}}{T_{so}}\Big)=|W|$

Thus for the presence of any number of heat reservoirs between $T_{so}$ and $T_{si}$, net work done in carnot engine remains same as that of one carnot engine between $T_{so}$ and T_{si}$.

Also net change of entropy = $\Big(\frac{Q_{source}}{T_{so}}-\frac{Q_o}{T_o}\Big)+\Big(\frac{Q_o}{T_o}-\frac{Q_{sink}}{T_{si}}\Big)=\Big(\frac{Q_{source}}{T_{so}}-\frac{Q_{sink}}{T_{si}}\Big)=\Big(\frac{T_{so}}{T_{so}}-\frac{T_{si}}{T_{si}}\Big)=0$

**Case[3]** $T_{so}>T_{si}>T_o$

[image]

$|W_1|=\lvert Q_{source}\rvert\Big(1-\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}\Big)$
Here we have take into account the sign convention as $W_1$ and $W_2$ are in opposite direction. Work done by system is negative and work done on system is positive.
$W_1$ is work done by system so negative.
As $T_o<T_1$, so $1-\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}>0$ and $W_1>0$. So multiply it by -1.
$W_1=-\lvert Q_{source}\rvert\Big(1-\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}\Big)=|Q_{source}|\Big(\frac{T_o-T_{so}}{T_{so}}\Big)$

Now, $\eta'=\eta_{refrigerator}=\lvert\frac{Q_o}{W_2}\rvert=\lvert\frac{Q_o}{Q_{sink}-Q_o}\rvert$
So, $\lvert\frac{W_2}{Q_o}\rvert=\lvert\frac{Q_{sink}-Q_o}{Q_o}\rvert=\lvert\frac{Q_{sink}}{Q_o}-1\rvert=\lvert\frac{Q_{sink}}{Q_o}\rvert-1=\frac{T_{si}}{T_o}-1$
$\implies |W_2|=|Q_o|\Big(\frac{T_{si}}{T_o}-1\Big)=|Q_{source}|\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}\Big(\frac{T_{si}}{T_o}-1\Big)=|Q_{source}|\Big(\frac{T_{si}}{T_{so}}-\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}\Big)$
As, $T_{si}>T_{so}$, so $|W_2|>0$. As $W_2$ is the work done on the system, $W_2=|W_2|$
So, $W_2=|Q_{source}|\Big(\frac{T_{si}}{T_{so}}-\frac{T_o}{T_{so}}\Big)$

Now, $W_1+W_2=-|Q_{source}|\Big(1-\frac{T_{si}}{T_{So}}\Big)$
So, net work is done by the system as $W_1+W_2$ is negative.
Thus, $|W_1+W_2|=|Q_{source}|\Big(1-\frac{T_{si}}{T_{So}}\Big)=|W|$

So, as $T_{so}>T_o$ and $T_o$ is further less than $T_{si}$, the first carnot engine does more work than the first carnot engine in the second case for same heat input $Q_{source}$ (as there is more difference in the temperatures under which the first carnot engine is being operated in the third case). So, some work has to be done on the second carnot engine so that net work done by the two carnot engines is equal to the work done by the single carnot engine operating between $T_{so}$ and $T_{si}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It was helpful but I forgot to include that  To is the least temperature achievable .So second part of second process might be something like a refrigerator .Can you give a brief answer for this modified question ?

Comment: See the updated answer from the beginning.

Comment: "Work done by system is negative and work done on system is positive". If you are using the version of the first law where $\Delta U=Q-W$, then work done by the system is positive, not negative, and work done on the system is negative, not positive.

Comment: The expression for first law with the sign convention which I follow is $\Delta U=Q+W$, Internal energy of system increases when heat flows into it and work is done on it.

Comment: @Iti Ok, but in future I suggest you let people know which version of the first law you are using. I say this only because the version $\Delta U=Q-W$ is the currently mostly used version.

Answer (score 2):

> So where does the extra work that I get go?

You didn't get any extra work in scenario 2, if that's what you meant by "extra work".

See the Figures below.

FIG 1 is based on my understanding of your two scenarios (if it is incorrect, let me know and I will either edit or delete my answer).

The additional work output you got when you operate the heat engine between $T_{so}$ and $T_o$ instead of between $T_{so}$ and $T_{si}$ is used to operate the heat pump in moving the heat sent from $T_o$ back to $T_{si}$. As you can see, the net additional work of scenario 2 is zero.

This may be easier to understand if instead of a single heat engine operating between $T_{so}$ and $T_{o}$, you have two heat engines operating between these temperatures. See FIG 2.

The first heat engine is that of your first scenario and the second heat engine takes the heat that the first rejects to $T_{si}$, produces work $W_2$, and rejects heat $Q_{o}-W_2$ to $T_o$. The work $W_2$ is then inputed to the heat pump which takes heat $Q_{o}-W_2$ from $T_o$ adds the energy of the pump, $W_2$ returning heat $Q_o$ to $T_{si}$. The end result is the same as that for the original single heat engine operating between $T_{so}$ and $T_{si}$. A key point here is if a Carnot heat engine operates a Carnot heat pump between the same two temperatures, the net work done is zero.

Hope this helps.

[image]

[image]

Comment: thanks . I think I have to edit my question but due to my lack of sufficient knowledge I am not being able to put my thoughts into words

Comment: I edited my question. So maybe now my question already contains the answer. Just discovered it today morning using my oversized brain.Can you please check whether it's correct or not?

Comment: @Tekton_infernus There should be no overall increase in entropy if you are dealing with Carnot heat engines and heat pumps. Before I can go any further, you need to let me know if FIG 1 accurately describes your scenario 2. And if it doesn't what should it look like? Print it out and mark it up to show what scenario 2 is. Then take a picture of the marked up version and download it on your computer. Then you can drag and drop the JPEG file into  your post using the image icon.

Comment: ok,I'll do that

Comment: Great. I made a few edits on the figures, so use the latest version.

Comment: @Tekton_infernus Did you decide not to do it?

Comment: Sorry m8 .I'm little busy .Just got into college .

Comment: @Tekton_infernus Congrats and good luck.  Your major?

Comment: cs m8.Was inspired by Defcon.Then I thought it wouldn't be bad to study some h4ckin stuffs.Are you in college too?

Comment: @Tekton_infernus I graduated college in 1969

Comment: Sheesh Sir, you have some dust on your bones, ha ha.